# How to take inflation into account with House price index?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, education

I was doing an assessment test and this question popped up. I ended up skipping the question, but I still want to know how to take inflation into account when dealing with a question like this? I should mention maybe that I have absolutely no background in finance and neither was the position related to that. This is probably a basic mathematics concept that I am missing.

[image: Question]

Comment: Why did you tag it as contest-math?

Comment: The idea is that an increase in the Retail Price Index from $A$ to $B$ represents a money falling in value by a factor $A/B$. So if you have any background in math, you should be able to figure it out from there. :)

Comment: Apologies for the wrong tag. I assumed it implied basic math competitions. I have changed it. And thank you for the response!

Comment: contest-math means things like IMO or regional math contests. It tends to result in problems being closed as "off-topic", meaning that half the professors on the site can't see how to solve them! Or to put it differently, consider that tangling with them is a poor use of time and should be discouraged.